# Jpython ImportError: No module named cv2

Tags: python, importerror

**Code :**

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("C:\\workspace\\trawe\\python\\license_rec\\PlateRecog.py");
PyFunction func = (PyFunction)interpreter.get("StartPlateRecog",PyFunction.class);
PyObject pyobj = func.__call__(new PyString(imgBase64));
```